# PHP loop using foreach

Tags: php, loops

Here is the problem:-

I've got a table of results from sports matches called 'MatchResults' with the following fields

Player1
Player2
Player1GamesWon
Player2GamesWon
Player1Pts
Player2Pts
league_id

First I am running a query which will filter this table using a stored variable I already have, giving me a shorter collection of rows:-

```
$qry = "SELECT * FROM BadmintonMatchResults WHERE league_id = '$leagueid'";
```

I need to run through each row that is produced from the above query and use the values to update another table called 'LeagueTable'. The structure of LeagueTable is as follows:-

member_id
Played
Won
Lost
GamesWon
GamesLost
Difference
Points

These updates take the form of several SQL queries, for example:-

```
$qry = mysql_query("UPDATE LeagueTable SET Played = Played + 1 WHERE member_id = '$p1id'");
$qry = mysql_query("UPDATE LeagueTable SET Played = Played + 1 WHERE member_id = '$p2id'");

if($p1pts > $p2pts) {
    $qry = mysql_query("UPDATE LeagueTable SET Won = Won + 1 WHERE member_id = '$p1id'");
    $qry = mysql_query("UPDATE LeagueTable SET Lost = Lost + 1 WHERE member_id = '$p2id'"); 
}
else if($p2pts > $p1pts) {
    $qry = mysql_query("UPDATE LeagueTable SET Won = Won + 1 WHERE member_id = '$p2id'");
    $qry = mysql_query("UPDATE LeagueTable SET Lost = Lost + 1 WHERE member_id = '$p1id'"); 
}

$qry = mysql_query("UPDATE LeagueTable SET GamesWon = GamesWon + '$p1won' WHERE member_id = '$p1id'");
$qry = mysql_query("UPDATE LeagueTable SET GamesWon = GamesWon + '$p2won' WHERE member_id = '$p2id'");  
$qry = mysql_query("UPDATE LeagueTable SET GamesLost = GamesLost + '$p1won' WHERE member_id = '$p2id'");
$qry = mysql_query("UPDATE LeagueTable SET GamesLost = GamesLost + '$p2won' WHERE member_id = '$p1id'");

$qry = mysql_query("UPDATE LeagueTable SET Difference = GamesWon - GamesLost");
$qry = mysql_query("UPDATE LeagueTable SET Points = Points + '$p1pts' WHERE member_id = '$p1id'");
$qry = mysql_query("UPDATE LeagueTable SET Points = Points + '$p2pts' WHERE member_id = '$p2id'");
```

Ignore any $variables I have as I'm currently doing this off data entered in a form, but want to alter it so that it uses rows from another database instead. I also know that my queries can be condensed and combined, my main problem is looping round this collection of queries multiple times for different sets of values.

My questions are:-

1. How to I reference the fields from the first table in the queries I need to run? Obviously just listing the field name 'Player1' isn't going to work.
2. How do I loop through each row and run the above 2 queries along with 8 more similar ones.

Note: Some of these queries are already nested inside an IF statement so any loop would have to go outside of that.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Why not simplify your 2 queries into 1 query by using `IN` (or `OR`) rather than `=` in your `where` clause

Comment: There's no need to loop here, you can use joined queries. Also, avoid using the `mysql_*` family of functions. They're deprecated now.

Comment: Thanks for the idea about combining the queries. I can combine these two however the other 8 deal with different variables, so I'll look to see which of those I can combine as well. The reason I thought I needed to loop is because my first query on the MatchResults tables produces over 30 lines, and my 10 queries that update the LeagueTable table need to be run on each of the 30 returned rows from the MatchResults table

Comment: why do you need 10 updates for one table? Why them cannot be done in one?

Comment: I can do them in one I suppose. They all update the same table but they update different values based on the values from the other table. My main problem here however is running these 10 updates for each of the rows returned from the other table

Comment: use PDO +  prepared queries , but i suspect you have a db design problem here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to do things that way then please tell me that you are sanitising the data before you use it in SQL statements. If I types " 0' or 1=1  " as my input and you used that the SQL would not do what you expect it to do.

To lop and then use the data by reference name from one tot he next you would simply do this:

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0){
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

        // ... your loop here code here
        mysql_query("UPDATE LeagueTable SET Played = Played + 1 WHERE member_id = '" . $row['Player1'] . "'");

    }
}
```

To be honest this still looks like you've got a very inefficient way of doing things as you are making your MySQL socket work very hard. I would consider how much calculations you need to store and how many can be worked out in an aggregate SQL query.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am sanitising the data don't worry, but yes you're right, there probably is a much more efficient way to do it. I'm quite good with SQL but not with PHP so I'll focus on trying to condense what I'm asking MySQL to do to try and make it better. However, I implemented your solution and it's now working perfectly! Thanks for all you're help!